# Read numbers from many text files and average them Python

Tags: python, average, mean

I have just started python and I have about 6000 .txt files each containing few numbers in a column like:

file1.txt:

> 2
>
> 43
>
> 78

file2.txt:

> 98
>
> 12

```
    and so on
```

I want to read them and store them in an array and calculate its mean.
Mean of (2,43,78,98,12..) i.e. all numbers from all files should give 1 mean
When I read and store them, they look like:

> ['2, 43, 78', '98, 12',..]

...   ( I got rid of the '\n')
But when I use `ave = sum(a)\float(len(a))` I get an error.
What am I doing wrong?
Is there anything I missed or another way to do this?

Code:

```
import fnmatch
import os

rootPath = 'D:/Data'
pattern = '*.txt'
all_data = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        #print( filename )
        name = os.path.join(root, filename)
        str = open(name, 'r').read()
        #print str
        all_data.append(str)
a=[item.replace('\n', ' ') for item in all_data]
#print a
for val in a:
    values = map(float, val.split(", "))
    ave = sum(values)/len(values)
    print ave
```

I get error:

> invalid literal for float()

Comment: please post the code and error details

Comment: strings are not numbers you need to run them (and not their length, which is an odd choice) one by one through `float()`

Comment: @Iabmat: You need mean of each file individually or all files?

Comment: Hello @labmat you need to create a folder put all the files in that folder and you need to try out scripting in python to read files and then you can find the average this is the very basic approach i explained there can be more ways of doing this task some might be better and efficient, just try first and post some code that you tried with people would help you further in doing your task done

Comment: @ Pavneet Singh Posted

Comment: @ anonymous One mean value which is mean of all files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sum("abc")` is not defined. Neither is `sum("2, 43")`. `sum` works only on numeric types.

You need to split the line first and convert the values to a numeric value (I used `float` here, because then the `sum` will be a `float`, so there is no need to convert the `len` to a `float`):

```
rows = ['2 43 78', '98 12']
total_sum = total_len = 0
for row in rows:
    values = map(float, row.split())
    total_sum += sum(values)
    total_len += len(values)
print total_sum/total_len
```

For Python 3.x replace the `print avg` with `print(avg)` and add a `list()` around the `map`, because otherwise `len` is not defined for it.

This is similar to what [@VadimK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5445395/vadim-k) has in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40265519/4042267), but avoids list addition and just does integer addition instead.

Comment: This worked for both my test and actual data! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

Simple approach using *list comprehension* as:

```
>>> my_list = ['2, 43, 78', '98, 12']
>>> my_nums = [float(j) for i in my_list for j in i.split(', ')] 
>>> avg = sum(my_nums)/float(len(my_nums))
>>> avg
46.6
```

Comment: Thank you for this! When I try this as you have posted I get correct answer, but on my data I get:  invalid literal for float()

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be better to map numbers after reading file like:

```
total_list = []
for file in files:
    str_list = file.read().splitlines() # ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
    int_list = map(int, str_list) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    total_list += int_list
ave = sum(total_list) / float(len(total_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple method using `glob` for linux

```
import glob
tot_list=[]
for i in glob.glob('*.txt'):        #Return a list of .txt files in current directory
#    print('file:', i)
    with open(i) as f:              #Open file, read lines
        lines = f.readlines()
        for x in lines:             # process each line
            try:
                x=int(x)            #Test for integer value
                tot_list.append(x)  #Include in list
            except:
                pass
print('Total:',sum(tot_list),'No of Items:',len(tot_list))
print('Mean : %.2f' % (sum(tot_list)*1.0/len(tot_list))) #Print floating point result to 2 decimal places
```